# etale morphism and direct image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be an etale morphism, where $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective
varieties. Let $V$ be a vector bundle over $Y$. Since $f$ is flat, $V$ is flat over $X$.
Is it true that $f_*V$ is flat $\mathcal{O}_X$-module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $Y$ and $X$ are proper over the base field, the morphism $f$ is finite (by Zariski's main theorem). Hence by the semi-continuity theorem (see Hartshorne p. 288, Cor. 12.9), $f_*V$  is locally free, because $f$ is finite and flat. So the answer is yes.

Comment: alternatively, the result holds simply because $f$ is affine, since it is finite (you don't actually need the semi-continuity theorem).